# React-Redux syntax error "," expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

New to this.

...and this is probably very simple. I have looked at the code for the const "selectData" and I cannot find where a comma is suppose to go. Here is the entire file:

```
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
        saveJwt(data)

        selectData()

      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message })
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }

const selectData = () => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })

  const token = jwt.access_token
  const headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  })
  const selectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: data })
        .catch(error => {
          clearJwt()
          dispatch({ type: ERROR_SELECT_DATA, payload: error.message })
        })
    }
}
```

The error is on the very last curly bracket and it says:

> Unexpected token, expected , (72:0)

line 72 is the last curly bracket.

If I remove the const expression that is "selectData" its OK - no errors. The error only appears when I add in that block of code... i.e its in the following:

```
const selectData = () => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })

  const token = jwt.access_token
  const headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  })
  const selectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: data })
        .catch(error => {
          clearJwt()
          dispatch({ type: ERROR_SELECT_DATA, payload: error.message })
        })
    }
}
```

Why is this block of code causeing an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a `)` on the last `then`:

```
.then(data => {
  dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: data })
    .catch(error => {
      clearJwt()
      dispatch({ type: ERROR_SELECT_DATA, payload: error.message })
    })
}) // <--- here
```

And you should always use `;`. I recommend you to use a linter to check your code, like [ESLint](http://eslint.org/)

Comment: I expected a -1 as its super basic but  for the life of me I couldnt find it.. cheers

Comment: Next time use a linter, most of the editors can be integrated with them.